# How to respond correctly to an axios request to an AWS API Gateway

Tags: amazon-web-services, axios, aws-api-gateway

I am currently trying to set up an AWS lambda that puts records into a mysql database. When calling the responsible API via an axios request, the lambda does get triggered and completes without thorwing any errors.

Lambda:

```
exports.registerUser = async (event,contex,callback) => {
data = JSON.parse(event.body)
console.log(data)

con = mysql.createConnection({
    host: "host",
    user: "name",
    password: "password",
    database: 'component'

  });
await con.connect(function(err) {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err)
      throw err;
    }     
    console.log("Connected!");
})

var timestamp = Date.now();
id_user =uuidv4();
var sql_user = "INSERT INTO user (id_user, first_name, last_name, email, city, registration) VALUES ('"+id_user+"', '"+data.first_name+"', '"+data.last_name+"', '"+data.email+"', '"+data.city+"', "+timestamp+")"
await new Promise(function(resolve,reject){
    con.query(sql_user, function (err, result) {
        if (err) return reject(err);
        console.log("1 record inserted");
        resolve(result)
    });
}) 
await con.end(function(err) {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err)
      throw err;
    }     
    console.log("Disonnected!");
})


console.log('SUCCESS')
return callback(null, 'success')
```

}

However, on client side the axios request always does return a 502.

Client:

```
cloud.registerNode = async function(event, callback){
axios.post(API, JSON.stringify({
    id_user: event.id_user,
    edge_uuid: event.edge_uuid, 
    edge_name: event.edge_name, 
    edge_key: event.edge_key, 
    cloud_key: event.cloud_key

})).then(function(response){
    console.log('It worked with response:')
    console.log(response)

}).catch(function(err){
    console.log('error thrown:')
    console.log(err)
})
```

}

I am suspecting that callback is not the right way to go here, but I am not sure how to do this correctly. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Check your Cloudtrail logs for the Lambda to see what's happening. Are you using Proxy Integration?

Comment: I am not using Proxy Integration (as far as I know). I already checked CloudWatch to see if the lambda fails, which it does not. I am not sure how to use CloudTrail in this context.

Comment: Sorry I meant CloudWatch. Ivan's answer should do the trick.

Comment: No problem. Thank you for taking the time.

Answer (score 1):

Drop the callback your Lambda function is async. You can return it like:

```
return {
  statusCode: 200,
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  },
  body: JSON.stringify('Success')
}
```

For the cases where you know the request is wrong you can do:

```
return {
  statusCode: 400,
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  },
  body: JSON.stringify('Bad Request')
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm currently doing something similar with a DynamoDB database and using the following code to call the API gateway to trigger my POST Lambda,

```
  handleSubmit = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log('state', this.state);

    const { records, record, album, artist, date, imageUrl } = this.state;
    const newRecord = { record, album, artist, date, imageUrl };

    fetch("https://vv2qx5zqb7.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/Dev", {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      },      
      body: JSON.stringify({records: record, album, artist, date, imageUrl})
    });
```

This is how Amazon describes using async,
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/nodejs-prog-model-logging.html

console.log('Loading function');

```
exports.handler = async function(event) {
    //console.log('Received event:', JSON.stringify(event, null, 2));
    console.log('value1 =', event.key1);
    console.log('value2 =', event.key2);
    console.log('value3 =', event.key3);
    return event.key1 // Echo back the first key value   
};
```